# UIView with custom drawRect and animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, core-animation, calayer

I have a `UIView` subclass that displays circular progress:

[image: circular progress view]

Screenshot above shows progress with value of `0.667`.

Inside my `UIView` subclass implementation in `drawRect:` method I am drawing two circles - one for background oval (gray), second for actual progress oval (blue). [(Check out source code)](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS/blob/9105e5fac3a4e50e1ceeeab5ae0b11f56a5142bd/DRCircularProgress/DRCircularProgressView.m#L34-L71)

It works like expected, but doesn't allow to animate progress changes. I tried to find solution that allows using `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:animations:` class method like this:

```
MyCustomView *progressView = ...
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 
                 animations:^{
                     progressView.progressValue = 1.f;
                 }];
```

But I wasn't able to make it animates that way.

You can check out the source code in [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS).

However, I found a way to perform an animation whenever `progressValue` changes. It's not exactly what I want (still not working with `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:animations:`), and I am not sure if this is the right direction. It involves subclassing `CALayer` of my `UIView`. You can check out the source code in the same repo mentioned above, [on custom_layer branch](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS/tree/custom_layer). Here is [direct link](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS/blob/c6e0088114522a092b14856c99442729619ebedb/DRCircularProgress/DRCircularProgressLayer.m#L24-L87) to `CALayer` subclass drawing implementation.

My question is: Having a `UIView` subclass that draws some shapes based on custom properties (`progressValue`), is it possible to make the view animates with `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:animations:` when changing the view's property (`progressValue`) ?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [rounak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29881830/514181) I get rid of drawing custom shapes in `drawRect:` method and created two separate `CAShapeLayer`s. Instead of drawing new shapes every time `progressValue` changes, I am just setting `strokeEnd` properties for that layers, which gives the same visual effect as before, but should perform better ([check out source code](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS/blob/aa8a9a6a88099910c3c37486f983a02b479ad1ed/DRCircularProgress/DRCircularProgressView.m)).

Then I implemented `actionForLayer:forKey:` method ([check out source code](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS/blob/aa8a9a6a88099910c3c37486f983a02b479ad1ed/DRCircularProgress/DRCircularProgressView.m#L76-L103)), which returns `CABasicAnimation` that should animate `strokeEnd` whenever `progressValue` changes.

However, I am still experiencing an issue with the animation:

```
__block NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
[UIView animateWithDuration:3
                 animations:^{
                     self.progressView.progressValue = 1.f;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished1) {
                     NSLog(@"first animation completed in %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date]);
                     date = [NSDate date];
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:3
                                      animations:^{
                                          self.progressView.progressValue = 0.f;
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished2) {
                                          NSLog(@"second animation completed in %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:date]);
                                          [self animateProgress];
                                      }];
                 }];
```

My circular progress view animates `progressValue` changes, and executing the code above tells that each animation takes about 3 seconds. Unfortunately, on screen the view animates very fast (animation completes in fraction of a second). Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I am not sure where the problem is, but I noticed that changing keypath in `[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"]` from `strokeEnd` to anything else doesn't gives any effect (animation always looks the same).

Any hints of what I am missing here will be appreciated.

**UPDATE 2**

I have just noticed that animation is in fact triggered by those two lines in `setProgressValue:` setter:

```
self.progressOvalLayer.strokeEnd = MIN(1, MAX(0, progressValue));
self.backgroundOvalLayer.strokeEnd = MIN(1, MAX(0, 1 - progressValue));
```

([see on GitHub](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS/blob/aa8a9a6a88099910c3c37486f983a02b479ad1ed/DRCircularProgress/DRCircularProgressView.m#L50-L51))

It looks like my implementation of `actionForLayer:forKey:` does not work at all, despite being executed (checked with brakepoint).

I wonder what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE - SOLUTION FOUND**

It occurred that I tried to animate main layer of my `UIView` instead of custom layers that contains oval shapes. I needed to fix `actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:` implementation to make it works ([check out fixed source code](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS/blob/b49bc578d1385d5f338cd9a026a20c843b14d5b6/DRCircularProgress/DRCircularProgressView.m#L74-L112)). That solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you draw the circular progress with a `CAShapeLayer`, and use the `strokeStart`, `strokeEnd`, and `fillColor` properties to achieve your effect. You'll likely need two shapeLayers, one over the other, but the advantage with this approach is that shapeLayer's properties are animateable via CoreAnimation.

Additionally, you can use hackery like this to make it animate within animation blocks as well https://gist.github.com/nicklockwood/d374033b27c62662ac8d

Comment: Thanks for hints, I updated my implementation and the question. Unfortunately, I am still not able to perform animations correctly. Please, check out my updated question.